# Compile-time check that a variable is signed/unsigned

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, macros

I'm trying to come up with some compile-time ways to check if a certain variable is signed or unsigned. Actually, I was using the following macro for quite some time to check for a signed variable:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define CHECK_SIGNED(v) if((v) == -(v)){}
#else
#define CHECK_SIGNED(v)
#endif
```

and then the following will pass it:

```
INT rr = 0;
CHECK_SIGNED(rr);
```

while the following:

```
UINT rr = 0;
CHECK_SIGNED(rr);
```

will generate a compile-time error:

> error C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result
>   still unsigned

So now I am trying to come up with a similar check for `unsigned` variable. Any suggestions?

PS. Although I'm using `VS 2017` it'd be nice to make it backwards compatible with older C++ standards.

Comment: `static_assert(std::is_signed_v<T>)`?

Comment: Relying on said error is not a portable way to check for this. There's no guarantee that the compiler will warn about that or that an option will be used to turn warnings into errors.

Comment: @chris: yes. But I thought I marked it as for VS2017.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could use something like this :

```
static_assert(std::is_signed<decltype(rr)>::value, "Not signed number");
```

and the sister version [`std::is_unsigned`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_unsigned)

Also, those are not very difficult to implement on your own for supporting old compilers.

Comment: Thanks. Although it requires a newer C++ standard, it's a working solution. So I'll mark it as the answer.